# how to sort Map[Int,Map[String,String]] according to inner map value

Tags: scala, sorting, collections, dictionary, scala-collections

How to sort `Map[Int,Map[String,String]]`?

```
var data=Map(1416479696353 -> Map(name -> You,savePoint -> 4), 1416479788969 -> Map(name -> You, savePoint -> 9), 1416479801372 -> Map(name -> govind,savePoint -> 10))
```

i want to sort above `map` according to `savePoint`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sortBy`:

```
data.toSeq.sortBy(_._2("savePoint").toInt)
```

This will give you a `List[(Int, Map[String, String])]`. If you only need the values of `data`, you can sort `data.values.toSeq` instead.